# update property value in xml file by reading it from properties file

Tags: xml, powershell, properties

I have a properties files with below entries:-

```
DBconn=xlvxdev.cumulus.com,1615;Initial Catalog=FPTR_XLVX;Security=true;
WebErrString=off
XLVXProvidername=Client.Data.OraclieClient
```

I have another xml file as below with above properties name between @@ @@.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigValues>
   <Connstring>
     add name="connXLVX" connectionString="Data Source=@@DBconn@@" providerName="@@XLVXProvidername@@"/>
   </Connstring>
   <WebErrormode="@@WebErrString@@" />
</ConfigValues>
```

I am able to update given property from the config file as below but unable to loop through all the properties between @@ @@ and update them.

```
$proppath='C:\Desktop\dev.properties'
$webconfigpath= 'C:\Desktop\xml.config'
$AppProps = @{}
$AppProps = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content $proppath -raw)
(Get-Content $webconfigpath) -replace "@@DBconn@@", $AppProps["DBconn"] | Set-Content $webconfigpath
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the ability to *dynamically* determine each substitution string, based on the specific text of a *given match*:

In *PowerShell (Core) 6.1+*, you can use the following approach:

```
(Get-Content -Raw $webconfigpath) -replace '@@(\w+)@@', {
  $AppProps[$_.Groups[1].Value]
} | Set-Content $webconfigpath
```

Each match is passed as a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instance to the script block (`{ ... }`), where it can be accessed via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).

---

In earlier versions, including in *Windows PowerShell*, where script-block-based substitutions aren't yet supported with the `-replace` operator, direct use of the underlying .NET APIs is required:

```
[regex]::Replace((Get-Content -Raw $webconfigpath), '@@(\w+)@@', {
  param($m)
  $AppProps[$m.Groups[1].Value]
}) | Set-Content $webconfigpath
```

Comment: This is awesome, didn't know using a scriptblock was possible.

Comment: Yes, @SantiagoSquarzon, it's quite handy; it's unfortunate that it's not available in Windows PowerShell. What _is_ available there - though far less useful and therefore rarely seen - is the ability to pass script blocks to `-split`, where each character in the input string is passed to `$_`; e.g.: `'foobar' -split { $_ -in 'o', 'a' }`

Comment: Didn't know that either lol I'm hoping for the day PS core will become the standard for companies.