# Trim leading spaces, then Capitalize first letter of every line, and add new line + string + $var from another file if line begins w specific string

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two files. One is structured questions, the other is an answer key.

SourceQuiz.txt sample:

```
1)This is the first question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
2)This is the second question
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
3)This is the third question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
4)This is the fourth question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4 
etc etc
```

AnswerKey.txt sample:

```
a
b
d
d
```

I need FinalQuiz.txt file to be in this format: https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Aiken_format

```
What is the correct answer to this question?
A. Is it this one?
B. Maybe this answer?
C. Possibly this one?
D. Must be this one!
ANSWER: D
```

The fact that the source questions have ) rather than . is immaterial. Moodle interprets them fine.

So I need to:

1. Strip the number and right parenthesis from the beginning of each question
2. Trim the leading spaces from the beginning of each question's options
3. Capitalize the first letter of each line
4. then look for every line beginning with D and insert a new line with the string `ANSWER: x` where x is the value in the line corresponding to the question in AnswerKey.txt

So i know i can:

```
Get-Content $SourceQuiz.txt  | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()}
```

and i know i can:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\123.txt | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_) {
    $_.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + $_.Substring(1)
  } else {
    $_
  }
} > output.txt
```

And i know i can use `if ($_.StarsWIth("D")` in a foreach loop to find lines beginning with D.

What I dont know how to do is nest foreach loops in one another to do these either all at once or in a specific order, nor how to add the value of the right line in AnswerKey.txt (in our example above Question 1 would be `ANSWER: A`, Question 2 would be `ANSWER: B`, Question 3 would be `ANSWER: D`, Question 4 would be `ANSWER D`.

I could probably get this done if i make multiple scripts, but im not sure. ive been banging my head over this for a bit.

---

Edit for clarification. Here is source once again:

```
1)This is the first question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
2)This is the second question
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
3)This is the third question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
4)This is the fourth question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
```

The result I'm getting:

```
This is the first question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: D
This is the second question
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: C
This is the third question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: A
This is the fourth question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4 
ANSWER: B
```

The result needed:

```
1)This is the first question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: D
2)This is the second question
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: C
3)This is the third question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4
ANSWER: A
4)This is the fourth question.
a)  option 1
b)  option 2
c)  option 3
d)  option 4 
ANSWER: B
```

The numbers are missing. These are the indicators the importer looks for to define the end of one question and the beginning of the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could think of, there is probably a much better way.

Props to mklement0 and [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568209/update-property-value-in-xml-file-by-reading-it-from-properties-file) where I learnt about script-block-based substitutions :)

**NOTE:** This code is all assuming the data looks exactly as you have shown in your question.

```
# In your case, this would be:
# $sourceQuiz = Get-Content path\to\SourceQuiz.txt

$sourceQuiz = @'
1)This is the first question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
2)This is the second question
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
3)This is the third question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
4)This is the fourth question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4 
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# And this would be:
# $answers = Get-Content path\to\answers.txt

$answers = @'
a
b
d
d
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$answerIndex = 0
$loopIndex = 1
$txtInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo

$sourceQuiz -split '^\d+\)' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {

    [regex]::Replace($_, '\s+(\w+)\)\s+', {
        param($s)
        
        $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($s.Groups[1].Value) + '. '
    })
    
    if($loopIndex % 5 -eq 0)
    {
        'ANSWER: {0}' -f $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($answers[$answerIndex])
        ''
        $answerIndex++
    }
    
    $loopIndex++
}
```

The above results in:

```
This is the first question.
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4
ANSWER: A

This is the second question
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4
ANSWER: B

This is the third question.
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4
ANSWER: D

This is the fourth question.
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4 
ANSWER: D
```

---

#### EDIT

Code above was always assuming the number of options would be 4, supposing there would be an unknown number of options, the code would look like below.

**Note the usage of `-Raw` on `Get-Content`.**

```
# In your case, this would be:
# $sourceQuiz = Get-Content path\to\SourceQuiz.txt -Raw # => -Raw is important here

$sourceQuiz = @'
1)This is the first question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
2)This is the second question
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
  c)  option 3
  d)  option 4
  e)  option 5
  f)  option 6
3)This is the third question.
  a)  option 1
  b)  option 2
'@

# And this would be:
# $answers = Get-Content path\to\answers.txt # => Here don't use -Raw

$answers = @'
a
b
d
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$answerIndex = 0
$txtInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo

$sourceQuiz -split '\d+\)' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
    
    $lines = $_ -split '\r?\n' -ne ''

    for($i=0;$i -lt $lines.Count;$i++)
    {
        switch($i)
        {
            {$i -eq 0}
            {
                $lines[$i]
                break
            }
            {$i -gt 0}
            {
                [regex]::Replace($lines[$i],'\s+(\w+)\)\s+',{
                    param($s)
        
                    $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($s.Groups[1].Value)+'. '
                })
            }
            {$i -eq $lines.Count-1}
            {
                'ANSWER: {0}' -f $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($answers[$answerIndex])
                ''
            }
        }
    }

    $answerIndex++
}
```

Now this would look like this:

```
This is the first question.
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4
ANSWER: A

This is the second question
A. option 1
B. option 2
C. option 3
D. option 4
E. option 5
F. option 6
ANSWER: B

This is the third question.
A. option 1
B. option 2
ANSWER: D
```

---

- Why is `-Raw` needed for the 2nd code snippet?

Because when reading the file if you use `-Raw`, the content will be a single `multiline string` instead of an array of strings `string[]`.

- Why a single `multiline string` is required?

Because, since the 2nd code snippet is assuming that the number of possible options will **not always** be 4, we need to find a way to determine how many options there are.

For this, it takes the content of the file a single `string` and splits where there are _any amount of digits followed by a `)` (i.e. `1)`, `123)`, `9999)`, etc) which separates each question and its corresponding options.

Once we have the questions an it's options divided in different arrays / chunks, we can split each chunk again in `carriage returns` or `new lines` and here we can assume that the `position 0` of the array will always be the question:

```
{$i -eq 0}
{
    $lines[$i]
    break
}
```

The positions `greater than 0` of the array will be the options, here is where we `trim` the leading spaces and replace the character followed by `)` for the same character followed by `.` (i.e.:    `a)` for `A.`).

```
{$i -gt 0}
{
    [regex]::Replace($lines[$i],'\s+(\w+)\)\s+',{
        param($s)

        $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($s.Groups[1].Value)+'. '
    })
}
```

Lastly, to determine when we have reached the end of the available options and to know when to insert the `ANSWER:`, since I'm using a `for` loop and using the `$i` variable as `index`, on each iteration of the loop the `switch` is asking if `$i` is equal to `$lines.Count - 1` (if `$i` has reached the end of the array or last element of the array).

```
{$i -eq $lines.Count-1}
{
    'ANSWER: {0}' -f $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($answers[$answerIndex])
    ''
}
```

Comment: I like it, if that matters +1

Comment: @Daniel Of course it matters to me. Thanks Daniel.

Comment: there are always only 4 answers. however the number of questions (and as such answers) varies

Comment: The first code snippet should work fine then @ScottMcCune

Comment: Works great, thank you @SantiagoSquarzon I think I'm going to use the second one actually, just in case we run into an anomaly or a decision is made in the future that changes scope. Can you explain the reasoning behind -RAW on Get-Content? Why is that important? I'm looking to learn here, not just get the job done.  Is there a reason you commented out (in both code snippets) the Get-Content path\to lines?  Assuming i just remove the #. At the end, am i just piping out to a file after the final }? ie  '| Out-File FinalQuiz.txt' ?

Comment: @ScottMcCune see my last edit, did the best I could to explain the logic but the code itself is a bit complex to understand if you're just getting started with scripting or with powershell itself. Please if the answer was helpful consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Appreciate it @santiago however there's one issue with the script. It's trimming the first two spaces of EVERY line, rather than just the two leading/blank spaces before each questions options, as I stated. It should only trim blank spaces from the lines, not the number and ) from the questions. The fact that the numbers are missing is breaking the import

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon for some reason i couldnt tag you from my phone yesterday

Comment: @ScottMcCune im not sure what you with the last comment, the output of my code looks pretty much the same as the expected output from your answer. If you want edit your question showing what you're getting as result and what would be the expected output instead.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon edited as requested.  The number and parenthesis are missing at the beginning of each question in the output.  I do not want to remove the first 2 characters from every line, i only want to remove *blank* spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @ScottMcCune If you want that out you would simply need to change `$sourceQuiz -split '\d+\)' -ne ''` for `$sourceQuiz -split '(?=\d+\))' -ne ''`, however the options are showing also with character followed by `)` when you stated that you wanted to capitalize the character and change the `)` for a `.`

Comment: Yeah I apologize @SantiagoSquarzon the instructions on the importer were not clear and I made an assumption based on its example.  The First criteria i listed `Strip the number and right parenthesis from the beginning of each question` was incorrect. I actually need to retain the number and parenthesis on the first line, but need to remove the leading spaces on the other lines.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I was able to do that easily by adding the '(?=\d\))' as you stated above, but tracking the error a bit further ive found I also need to add a space after each number and parenthesis.  So ive done some research and found that ?= is the look ahead and \d is defining that we're looking for a digit rather than a word, or any other character and I've been able to insert a space *before* this, but i cant seem to figure out how to insert the space *after* the ) before the first character of the next word.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon nevermind. I got it. it wasnt any of that. the importer was erroring out because the Out-File was saving as UTF-16 LE and the importer needs UTF-8.

I added ```-Encoding "UTF8"``` to the Out-File cmdlet and it works like a charm. sorry to be such a nag, but thank you much. I learned quite a bit.